# (gclalcli) error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg': Permission denied

Tags: python, linux

I'm in a battle with installing gcalcli.  I'm using [this setup](http://xmodulo.com/integrate-google-calendar-linux-desktop.html) since the other more simple methods aren't working.  I'm at the step where I have to type in sudo python setup.py install

I get:

```
running installenter code here
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing requirements to gcalcli.egg-info/requires.txt
writing gcalcli.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to gcalcli.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to gcalcli.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'gcalcli.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'gcalcli.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
warning: install_lib: 'build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7' does not exist -- no Python modules to install

creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
error: could not create 'build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg': Permission denied
```

At this point I had just given permissions to everything to even allow this to run, but I'm not sure what to do from here since it's telling me the python modules don't exist.

Comment: did you run he command with `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that sudo does not work when in an NFS mounted directory.  My /u/ directory is in a NFS mounted directory.  I had to created /tmp/module with root.  I then copied all the module files into /tmp/module and did: "python setup.py install" as root; and it worked.